# Adding drop down selection in alert popup inside [filename.ts]

Tags: angular, ionic3

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/popup-input/124197/2

Hi everyone i have a question. is it possible to add a dropdown selection below this inputs? i search many times for this and nothing is relevant. i think the problem is i don't know what to search for this. i need you guys to help me with this. thank you for your future answers.

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentPrompt() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Login',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'username',
        placeholder: 'Username'
      },
      {
        name: 'password',
        placeholder: 'Password',
        type: 'password'
      }
    ],

  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implement selector in the alert popup box"?

Comment: hi sir, i mean is it possible to add a drop down selection below in that inputs?
-thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs says for `ion-alert`:

> Alerts can also include several different inputs whose data can be passed back to the app. Inputs can be used as a simple way to prompt users for information. **Radios, checkboxes and text inputs** are all accepted, but they cannot be mixed.

So it appears you can't have drop downs in your alert
Layout. If you want a complex layout (e.g. a drop down in your layout), I suggest you to use a `popover` or a `modal`. I leave a link to the documentation of each one below:

`ion-popover`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover

`ion-modal`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal